# String padding not taking up the same character spacing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using padding in my `UITableViewSource` to format a cell. I have:

```
//cell declared somewhere in `UITableViewSource`
```

`var name = rows[indexPath.Row].MachineName.PadRight(50);`

I have tried this as well:

`var name = rows[indexPath.Row].MachineName.PadRight(50, ' ');`

I have some set the cell text:

`cell.TextLabel.Text = "01234567" + " " + name + "01234567";`

The output looks like:

```
01234567 SomeNameHere           01234567
-------------------------------------------
01234567 SomeNameHere           01234567
--------------------------------------------
01234567 SomeOtherNameHere         01234567
--------------------------------------------
01234567 ShortName            01234567
---------------------------------------------
```

I have checked the length of `name` and all of them are 50 but when its shown on my device in the cell it doesn't line up. Is there something special with Xamarin, iOS, `UITableViewCell` - something that may be different.

My work around for this would be to create a UITableViewCell using XCode but it would be nice if this could work.

Comment: By default, it is not using a Monospaced font.

Comment: One solution would be to use separate labels for each column

Comment: @MartinR Thats what I was thinking I would do if I couldn't get around this another way

Comment: Yes, use a monospaced font.  However, if you are trying to align data in columns, using a custom cell with individual labels is probably a better approach.  You could also try the tab spacing trick that Lawrence suggests.

Comment: @jharr100: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18926262/1187415 . You can create an "attributed string" with tab stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a monospaced font as suggested by @Jason and it seems Courier New is the only one available in iOS just from my quick search.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var name = rows[indexPath.Row].MachineName.PadRight(10, '\t');
```

Comment: no this produces something that looks like            `01234567 SomeNameHere01234567`

Comment: Well, try changing it to a bigger count than 4. Maybe 10 or 12?

Comment: this isn't working...adding additional tabs worked for spacing but the alignment is still off